# using paws in R -- listing AWS workspaces

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces, r-paws

I'm wanting to use paws in R to list out the AWS Workspaces.  I'm seeing reference to it in the [documentation](https://github.com/paws-r/paws/blob/main/R/workspaces_operations.R) however get a 404.

```
library(paws)

Sys.setenv(
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "*****************",
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "******************",
  AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
)

paws::??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you found the reference (which however, as you say, returns 404) but the [list of services supported by paws](https://paws-r.github.io/docs/) doesn't include workspaces.

Additionally, if in R Studio you start typing `paws::` you don't get any autocompletion for workspaces at all.

It seems that, at least in the current version (0.3.4) of paws, workspaces are not supported.